# How to add random x, 0, z movement to GameObjects on Terrain?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I'm inexperienced with UnityScript and C#, and a solution I can study would be greatly appreciated.

The behavior I want is for Pickups to move in random directions on a terrain, changing direction if they encounter a rigid body or static object.

I tried the script "Wander.cs" available here: 
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Wander

However, when played, the script turns the game object on end, and I cannot correct this. Also, objects tend to pool in corners instead of heading away.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities as far as I can understand your query.

I didn't try but hope it helps.

1- With help of parametric equation of circle i.e.

**x=v.t.cos(theta)

y=v.t.sin(theta)**

In you case:

**x=v.t.cos(theta) + xDistance

z=v.t.sin(theta) + zDistance**

where **xDistance** and **zDistance** are simple initial position value of your body. These value will not be changed after starting movement (during movement **until collision occur**).

In Update() apply these equations to your body with constant **v** and **theta** and increase **t (t++ or t+= 0.1f)** by time. When body collides, just retain the current translate (position) value. And start movement again, this time change the value of **xDistance** and **zDistance** with current value but only once.

2- With help of **iTween**. Its a free animation script available at [Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/84)

You can use iTween.MoveTo to move body to any given direction (You can assign a random direction as well.). And stop and restart movement upon collision.